# Consider all inherited classes when using typeof

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have several classes (one of which is called `Pet`) that extend the class `Animal`. If I have a generic method, can I use `typeof` to compare with the base class?

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Animal))
{
    return ((Animal)pet).Color;
}
```

What's currently happening in my code is that this clause is getting skipped entirely. This isn't desired in this particular example, since `Pet` inherits from `Animal`.

Comment: Why don't you try running it to find out.  Note though that even if you could, you *shouldn't*.  It's usually a sign of poorly designed code to need to explicitly check an object's type.

Comment: Use `if(pet is Animal)` or `Animal a = pet as Animal; if (a != null) return a.Color;`

Comment: @Servy I am asking the question because the code I currently have doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to use generic restraints? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: If you need to do stuff such as this it is almost always due to bad design. Your class/function will become hard to maintain and to extend. Try to use some polymorphism.

Comment: @gjdanis - Servy's point is that likely your code is not the recommended way of achieving what you actually want to implement. Explaining what your actual goal is along with concrete problem would make question much easier to answer the way it would be useful for you.

Comment: @Alexei The design isn't mine. This is just a bug in some code I'm working on and am looking for a quick fix.

Comment: @gjdanis If it's not working then explain what about it isn't working.  Does it not compile?  If so, what is the error.  Does it throw an exception when running, if so, what?  Does the check pass/fail when you think it shouldn't, if so, explain the data and expected output, etc.

Comment: @gjdanis Quick fixes = long term solutions = future headaches

Comment: @Andrew `Quick fixes = long term solutions` wait what?

Comment: @gjdanis Given your edit, then you *know* it's not working, you don't need to ask if it will work.  Asking "will this work" is very rarely as sensible question.  Run it and find out.  If it's not working ask how to do whatever you need to do instead.

Comment: @Andrew quick fixes == future headaches :/

Comment: @Servy: I was asking if it's possible to use `typeof`. It seems that `typeof` is not the route to go and needs to used alongside `IsAssignableFrom`.

Comment: @gjdanis, You can also use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) along with the target type (I've included that in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `typeof(T) == typeof(Animal)`, do:

```
var animal = pet as Animal;
if(animal != null)
  return animal.Color;
```

This saves you an extra type check.

**Note about `as` and `is`**

`as` can only be used for reference types. If you try to cast using `as` and it fails... it will return `null`.  If you JUST want to check to see if a value is of a certain type, use `is`. It returns a `boolean`.

**`Where` keyword**

But, lets also look at what you can do with generics!

```
public void Foo<T>(T pet)
  where T : Animal
{
}
```

Notice the `where` keyword. This will force at compile time that `T` is of type `Animal`.  This way... you never even have to verify!

Which means your function could look like:

```
public void Foo<T>(T pet)
  where T : Animal
{
  return pet.Color;
}
```

Cleaner and faster!

Comment: That "note about as and is" is incorrect because of too much generality. It will not return the default value of whatever you tried to cast to. In fact it will, but that default value is always `null`. You can't use the `as` operator for types that aren't reference types. And all reference types have a default value of `null`. Imagine the clumsy design in which `ANYTHING_OTHER_THAN_A_BOOL as bool` would return `false`. Try to picture such a world and keep in mind that there are precisely two values for `bool`. One half of those values would be a catch-all for anything other than `true` :)

Comment: @EduardDumitru That is false.  You can use `as` with nullable value types, which are not reference types, but in fact value types, and it *does* assign the default value of said types in the event that the type cast does not succeed.  Your proposed change would change a correct statement to an incorrect statement.

Comment: Fair enough... I didn't think about the fact that maybe it's not common knowledge that reference types are required.

Comment: @Servy Point taken. But still you understand my concern, right ? I am truly sorry to have been so drastic about something which was utterly incorrect *BUT* as you've said: "you can use `as` with nullable value types". That's *ONE* generic struct from the BCL plus its entourage of particularisations. I think it's important to mention this to people: It's reference types and then there's the `Nullable<whatever T>` and no other value type instead of simply saying that `default(T)` is what will come out of an `as` operation in general. So I agree. The answer is correct. Maybe just not pedagogical

Answer (score 2):

While I would personally go the route of the C# `as` operator for most of these situations (see Andrew's answer), you can also use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), depending on your needs:

```
if (typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    return ((Animal)pet).Color;
}
```

On a side note, I generally prefer `Type.IsAssignableFrom` over `Type.IsSubclassOf` because `IsAssignableFrom` also works with interfaces.

Oh, you could also use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
if (pet is Animal)
{
    return ((Animal)pet).Color;
}
```

Comment: Yes it would. The result of the invocation of `IsAssignableFrom` (as can be seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx ) is the value of truth of the question: can I do this: ` Source s = ...; Destination d = s; ` in an implicit manner ? Would this compile if I didn't touch any of the conversion operators ?